# What is the easiest way to make a two-dimensional table on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstableview

I want to create a two-dimensional table in iOS, something similar to NSTableView (not UITableView).

The user shouldn't be able to edit it, and the cells will only contain text.

Is there a class out there, that can make a table like this?

**Edit:**

I don't need support for user interactions at all.

I would just want something like this:

```
aaaaaa | bbbbb | cccccc
1111   | fff   | fffffffff
222    | 4444  | 44444
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, there are ready to use classes for that task, but on the other hand, those may or may not be exactly what you need.

Generally, what you want is an approach that sticks with the advantages of the `UITableView` (de/queing of cells). Hence my recommendation is a bit abstract but generally the pattern I used in the past;

Use the `UITableView` in connection with `UITableViewCell`s for covering the rows. Now, for covering the columns, devide the `UITableViewCell`s into tiles and once the `UITableView` asks you to provide the cells (`cellForRowAtIndexPath`), you render the cell out of your tiles and feed that row back to the `UITableView`.

Comment: tbh, I needed a grid view once, and rolled out my own implementation similar to this answer. @Tyilo, if your tableView is *that* simple, just write it this way. (Extra notes: Use `UITableViewStylePlain`, with `drawRect:` inside the custom `UITableViewCell` that will draw the lines between the inner cells.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [DTGridView](https://github.com/danielctull/DTGridView) - it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I know the author - and he's far more active on GitHub, so it's better off linking to that repository

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think a `GridView` would work in your case. You can treat each grid as a cell.

Here is the "simple" one (KKGridView):

http://maniacdev.com/2011/09/open-source-high-speed-interactive-ios-grid-view-component/

I would also recommend you take a look at a more sophisticated one with more options:

https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView

**EDIT:**

Well, it's also a fact that `AQGridView`is the "Winner of the Best Developer Tool/Helper award at iPadDevCamp 2010 in San Jose". But, it's a bit sophisticated, as I said.